# Remove high level field from JSON data

Tags: java, spring, response

One of our app APIs utilizes Java's Response method `.build()` to generate the response for our API, and return that to API consumers.  This is done via the code line `Response.ok().entity(responseVO).build();`.  We recently migrated to a new version, and we are seeing now that this line is wrapping our content in an Entity tag.  Our Response object went from

```
[
  {
    "field1":"hello",
    "field2":"world"
  },
  {
    "field1":"foo",
    "field2":"bar"
  }
],
"status":200,
...
```

However, after the upgrade, we are seeing that the first array is now being wrapped in an "entity" tag.

```
"entity":[
  {
    "field1":"hello",
    "field2":"world"
  },
  {
    "field1":"foo",
    "field2":"bar"
  }
],
"status":200,
...
```

Our API consumers depended on reading the response data without the "entity" tag, so I want to locally remove this tag and have the response in the old format.  Is there an easy way to do this?  My last resort is to convert this to an object and manipulate the JSON, but I would like to know if there is an easy way to go about this first.

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove that `entity` field name? It's not valid JSON without it. Not sure there's an easy way to *produce* invalid JSON with Jackson (or any other well-known JSON library for Java) so you may be stuck with a custom serialiser.

Comment: @MichaelBerry That...is a good point, I will look into how this was expected before

Answer (score 0):

Your **entity** field is correct as per JSON validation rule. Something weird can be seen as same code had generated **invalid** format before upgrade. Please check issues/bugs with your previous version of library.